# Mosfet parameters from Datasheet

Tags: mosfet, datasheet

Is it possible to find out the W/L ratio and process transconductance parameters of a mosfet from it's datasheet when it is not directly given ? If yes, how ?

Comment: No, you can't find it because we do not need one. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321904/mosfet-biasing-problems/321928#321928 and this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eE-8Q0vPUak&feature=youtu.be&t=5m58s

Comment: @G36 Your comment doesn't make logical sense. The fact that you don't need W/L doesn't imply or require that the information would be impossible to obtain or derive.

Comment: Decades ago, the International Rectifier Corporation introduced the power fet topology using hexagonal cells, many such cells, with the current flowing vertically.