# Saturation equation parameter datasheet

Tags: transistors, datasheet

Can anyone tell me if I look in a datasheet  ([this one for example](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BSH201.pdf))what is the parameter in it that gives me the value of \$\frac{1}{2}* \mu*C_{ox}*(\frac{W}{L})\$? I need this value to determine the current in saturation in a PMOS transistor.

Edit: added schematic
[image]

Comment: For what do you want to use your MOSFET? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321904/mosfet-biasing-problems/321928#321928

Comment: I want to use a pmos as a simple switch. 
I am making a pcb so i wanted to use a transistor with source connected to 5V and  the gate level is either 0V or 5V but i need to know the parameters to know the current in the node.

Comment: And the load maximum current is? In general, you picked the right MOSFET ( BSH201)  for a low-power switch (100mA).

Comment: I wanted the maximum current to be 300mA as it is connected to an LDO to power up an ESP32 MCU

Comment: The limiting value for that MOSFET is 300 mA so, look for one that has lower on resistance and higher maximum current. Also, post your target schematic.

Comment: But how do i calculate the value using datasheet parameters so that I can be sure the operation point of the circuit?